# Vector: clearing it vs deleting it

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++.

In every frame, I want to fill up a vector with data from different instances and process this data in a certain order, then rinse and repeat. This vector is going to be fairly large (with possibly 800+ elements),

My question is:

Is it faster to clear a vector than to just delete it and make a new one (of appropriate size to avoid allocations) each frame?

PS: The data being processed is dynamic hence why I need a clean state each frame.

Comment: Have you ran any tests? Including having one way in your program and noting whether it's quick to perform or not. Typically, you shouldn't need to worry about performance until you get to a bottle neck. Best not to spend your time wondering about the most performant way to do something.

Comment: 800-1000 elements is not very large even for quite old systems. With that said, don't fall into the trap of *premature optimizations*. Concentrate on working good, nice, readable and maintainable and well-designed code first of all.

Comment: Write your code then see if you need to optimize afterwards

Comment: i haven't ran any tests. but yes i might just be drowning in a glass of water here lol.

Comment: The terminology used set off some back-brain tingling. On the off chance you don't already know this, There is almost never a good reason to `new` or `delete` a `vector`. `vector` is designed to handle memory management for you in as safe a manner as possible. `new` and `delete` tosses that memory management back in the programmer's lap, and programmers are notoriously bad at always getting the memory management right..

Comment: Just use `vector<>::resize()`.

Comment: What is the element type?

Comment: @DavisHerring im working on a 2d game engine the data being handle is sf::sprite.

Comment: You might consider using some form of a resource manager, instead of a raw std::vector stroing sprites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize your vector to the size you think you'll need for the frame and keep a `size_t mCursor=0`

When you insert, increment the `mCursor++`; when you 'clear' for the next frame just set it to `mCursor=0`.

---

If you avoid resizing the vector during the frame, then the data will be at the same memory location for the duration of the frame.  Also, if you cap out `(mCursor >= vector.size)`, just drop the data and remember how many sprites you dropped.  Then resize the vector between frames.

Keep a Max counter for the cursor so you can update your source to start out with the larger vector.  At some point though, you might want to drop sprites, especially if you overload it with particles.

---

Perf Code:

```
// SpeedTestClearVector.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>


namespace sf
{
    class Texture;
    struct IntRect { int rect[4]; };
    struct FloatRect { float rect[4]; };
    struct RenderTarget { };
    struct Vertex { float verts[3]; float uv[2]; };
    enum RenderStates {};
    typedef IntRect Color;

    class Sprite // : public Drawable, public Transformable
    {
    public:
        Sprite() {}
        explicit Sprite(const Texture& texture) {}
        Sprite(const Texture& texture, const IntRect& rectangle) {}
        void setTexture(const Texture& texture, bool resetRect = false) {}
        void setTextureRect(const IntRect& rectangle) {}
        void setColor(const Color& color) {}
        const Texture* getTexture() const {}
        const IntRect& getTextureRect() const {}
        const Color& getColor() const {}
        FloatRect getLocalBounds() const {}
        FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const {}

    private:
        virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const {}
        void updatePositions() {}
        void updateTexCoords() {}

        Vertex         m_vertices[4]; ///< Vertices defining the sprite's geometry
        const Texture* m_texture;     ///< Texture of the sprite
        IntRect        m_textureRect; ///< Rectangle defining the area of the source texture to display
    };

} // namespace sf


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    const size_t reserve_size = 1024;
    const size_t iterations = 1000000;

    // Vector Clear
    {
        std::vector<sf::Sprite> spriteCache;
        spriteCache.reserve(reserve_size);

        time_t start_time = time(nullptr);

        for (size_t n = 0; n < iterations; ++n)
        {
            spriteCache.resize(reserve_size);
            spriteCache.clear();
        }

        auto total_time = difftime(time(nullptr), start_time);
        std::cout << "vector::clear() took " << total_time << " seconds of your life that you cannot have back." << std::endl;
    }
    // Output:
    // vector::clear() took 6 seconds of your life that you cannot have back.

    // Vector Cursor
    {
        std::vector<sf::Sprite> spriteCache;
        spriteCache.resize(reserve_size);
        size_t mCursor = 0;

        time_t start_time = time(nullptr);

        for (size_t n = 0; n < iterations; ++n)
        {
            spriteCache.resize(reserve_size); // does nothing, but included to be similar to previous test
            mCursor = reserve_size;
            mCursor = 0;
        }

        auto total_time = difftime(time(nullptr), start_time);
        std::cout << "Vector mCursor took " << total_time << " seconds of your life that you cannot have back." << std::endl;
    }
    // Output:
    // Vector mCursor took 0 seconds of your life that you cannot have back.


    // Vector "new" lol
    {
        time_t start_time = time(nullptr);

        for (size_t n = 0; n < iterations; ++n)
        {
            std::vector<sf::Sprite> spriteCache;
            spriteCache.resize(reserve_size); 
            spriteCache.clear();
        }

        auto total_time = difftime(time(nullptr), start_time);
        std::cout << "Vector 'new' took " << total_time << " seconds of your life that you cannot have back." << std::endl;
    }
    // Output:
    // Vector 'new' took 6 seconds of your life that you cannot have back.

    return 0;
}
```

> vector::clear() took 6 seconds of your life that you cannot have back.
>
> Vector mCursor took 0 seconds of your life that you cannot have back.
>
> Vector 'new' took 6 seconds of your life that you cannot have back.

Comment: your "cursor" idea is actually how `vector::size` works already, and in the second part, where you talk about "size", that is actually how `vector::capacity` works

Comment: Absolutely.  I totally agree.  Question: How many object destructors does `mCursor=0` call vs `vector::clear`?  Asking for a friend.

Comment: None in practice, since the destructor is trivial

Comment: The difference you observe is because you're doing a debug build where function calls are retained for debugging purposes. Even with only `-O1` I get `0` for both first 2 cases. You should use max optimization level for any meaningful benchmark result.

Comment: Nope, release build.

Comment: Add zeros to the end of iterations until you start getting actual numbers.

Comment: Figure out how to enable optimization in your compiler

Comment: @JamesPoag, Actually thats an awesome technique, i settle for the the pushback function and clearing at the end, but now that you mention it, there is actually no need to clear, i can just overwrite. Really appreciate the lesson.

Comment: Using `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1` With `Release x64` and Optimization set to `/O2`.  Sorry if my compiler is too janky, but the results stand.  I was wondering though, If I got results of `{ 0, 0 }` (which I did until I increased the `iterations`) would I consider it a valid test?  It's funny because I assumed that the trivial destructor would get optimized out, but instead of resting on the assumption, I plugged everything into a compiler to be certain.

Comment: @CPPapprentice No problem.  Just something I picked up a while back.

Answer (score 3):

You should expect `v.clear()` to be faster than `} {vector<T> v; v.reserve(old_size);` (where the two braces usually delimit the same loop body), simply because it does a subset of the work of the latter.  Both run destructors (if any) and set (the internal pointer behind) `end` to `begin`, but the latter also frees and (re)allocates memory, as well as containing more pointer assignments.  (`clear` doesn’t free the memory, since it does not [affect capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear).)

However, *hopefully* it doesn’t matter, especially if the vector is large and/or constructing/destroying the elements is expensive: it’s *conceptually* superior to limit a vector’s lifetime to the relevant loop iteration than to have it extend outside the loop until the (possibly distant) end of some enclosing block.  It would be possible to do so without sacrificing performance by using a custom allocator to keep the storage alive longer, but that requires an enclosing block for the allocator anyway and is generally cumbersome.